# No logro publicar una entrada blogger api

Tags: javascript, google-api, http-post

Al intentar publicar una entrada me da error 401 en la petición [HTTP/3 403 Forbidden 644ms] y no sé qué le hace falta a este código

```js
function tope() {
      
      
      let parameters = {
      
         "kind": "blogger#post",
         "blog": {
           "id": "696221704972086...."
          },
         "title": "Titulo",
         "content": "esto es un texto"
      }
      
      
      $.ajax({
      
      data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/696221704972086..../posts/",
      type: &quot;POST&quot;,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: {
      "Authorization": access_token
      },
      
      success: function(text) {
      
      console.log(text);
      
      }
      
      
      
      });
      
      
      
      
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="tope()">Publicar</button>
```

Comment: El error que estás sufriendo (403 Forbidden) es debido a que el testigo entregado al API no es válido. Recuerda que no puedes usar una clave de API para hacer operaciones de escritura en el API, solo se puede usar para acceder a datos públicos. ¿Cómo obtuviste el testigo de sesión?

Answer (score 0):

No estás indicando correctamente las credenciales obtenidas.

La cabecera [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) debe ser del tipo [`Bearer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#authentication_schemes):

```
Authorization: Bearer ....
```

Por lo que tu código debería ser el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
  data: ...,
  url: ...,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
  },
  success: function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
});
```